# How run IE in edge mode without devtools?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am currently running IE in edgemode but only when I use the devtools(F12). When I turn off the devtools it seems to be running in IE 7 mode. How can I change this without adjusting the registry? I am not an admin on this machine I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can use `Meta` tag:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>My Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Either you can use `Enterprise Mode Site List Manager`

2.1 [Use Enterprise Mode to improve compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility)

2.2 [Fix web compatibility issues using document modes and the Enterprise Mode site list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/fix-compat-issues-with-doc-modes-and-enterprise-mode-site-list)

Thanks :-)

Comment: one more link which I am unable to give inside answer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/use-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-manager